# Upload files to Microsoft Teams using API

Tags: java, file-upload, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an access token for Microsoft Graph. I have to upload file to the channels file tab.

Can anyone help which endpoints I need to use for upload file to file tab
I am calling below API:

PUT: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c8550c107aad/drive/items//sites/leafletcorp.com/Shared%20Documents/Development:/abc.docx:/content?@name.conflictBehavior=rename

I am getting below response:
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-05-05T09:12:42",
"request-id": "a517632c-13d0-491d-8b56-8020101be95d",
"client-request-id": "a517632c-13d0-491d-8b56-8020101be95d"
}
}
}

Comment: When you send some attachment to any chat, that file will be added to files tab. You can send a file attachment to chat using Graph API. Could you please check [Add Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-file-attachment)?try if that helps.

Comment: I am looking for add file without chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Files tab in channel is nothing it linked to SharePoint site default folder, Please take a look at [Upload Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) This API restricted to file size to 4MB. if you want to upload greater than 4MB please take a look at [Upload larger files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)